# How to assign generic ObservableCollection<T> to ObservableCollection of known T parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, generic-collections

I am even not sure, that the question is asked correctly, because I have no idea how to name it. Sorry if confusing, but I will try to explain what I dont know step by step. In my **VM** one of the methods is calling a **service** method:

```
public ObservableCollection<LoadedJockey> Jockeys { get; private set; }
Jockeys = await _updateDataService.UpdateDataAsync(Jockeys, JPlFrom, JPlTo, "updateJockeysPl");
```

The **service** method takes **argument** of type `ObservableCollection<T>`, so instead of `Jockeys` can be `Horses`, `Cars`, `Poneys` etc. And inside of my **service** method I need to assign to `ObservableCollection<LoadedJockeys>` (known type) that generic collection passed to the **parameter**, to get something like this:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> UpdateDataAsync<T>(ObservableCollection<T> genericCollection, int idFrom, int idTo, string jobType)
           if (jobType.Contains("Horses"))
           {
                  ObservableCollection<LoadedHorses> horses = genericCollection;
           }
           else if (jobType.Contains("Jockeys"))
           {
                  ObservableCollection<LoadedJockeys> jockeys = genericCollection;
           }
```

How to do it?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<LoadedJockeys> jockeys = new ObservableCollection<LoadedJockey>( genericCollection.OfType<LoadedJockey>.ToList());
`?

Comment: A lot of things are unclear. Is LoadedJockey type a base class for all the above classes (e.g Horses, Cars, Poneys etc.)? Do you want to convert every member of the collection to LoadedJockeys? Or do all these classes even have a way to cast them to LoadedJockeys?

Comment: I am sorry, but my example was not complete, just updated it now.

Comment: So you want every ObserveableCollection<[X]> to become ObserveableCollection<Loaded[X]>?

Comment: @iSpain17 that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the elements

```
ObservableCollection<LoadedJockeys> jockeys = 
new ObservableCollection<LoadedJockeys>(genericCollection.Cast<LoadedJockeys>());
```

or take only the matching elements

```
ObservableCollection<LoadedJockeys> jockeys = 
new ObservableCollection<LoadedJockeys>(genericCollection.OfType<LoadedJockeys>());
```